# how do i know what version of jqgrid i am using

Tags: jqgrid

i have a asp.net project and its using jqgrid as the javascript grid.  How can i find out what version of jqgrid is being used?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

have you tried opening up the file **jquery.jqGrid.min.js** and looking at the first line of comments?

Mine says;

```
/* 
* jqGrid  3.5.1 - jQuery Grid
```

Answer (score 8):

If you need to query the version programmatically you can use:

```
$.jgrid.version
```

**Example:**

```
alert($.jgrid.**version**);
```